# After closing my app, it won't re-open to viewController but goes straight to First viewController

Tags: xcode4, build, viewcontroller

After successfully completing my first very simple app following the great tutorial by profGustin https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHj7nQHqq2c
I added my own viewController to go before the tabController (which is how the app build started) and checked the box  "is initial View Controller" after unchecking it on the tabController.
The app is great and works fine on the first build and playback on my iphone but when I close it down on the iphone and go to re-open it, it always defaults to the firstViewController, which is a child of the tabController. I need to always open to ViewController. I also cannot see a .h or .m page for my ViewController. I'm sure this has something to do with some delegate coding but cannot find any answers after exhaustive search. 
Can anyone out there shine some light?
As you can guess, I am very new to this.

Many, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to restart the app from scratch every time it launches?

If that is the case then you want to change/add the key `Application does not run in background` (also known as: `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend`) in your info.plist file to `YES`. This will cause the app to launch from your rootview/initial controller every time.